# null and not null mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, null, notnull

Hi I have started moving access into mysql and I was wondering if there is a constraint or something I could use to be able to make a column not `null` and still have empty values in it?

This is not my own database, if it was I would just fill in the empty fields and then change the column to not `null`.

Comment: Switching a field from nullable to not-null should automatically fill it in with the default values in MySQL. The converse isn't true, though. Switching not null to nullable won't change fields with default values to null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are various approaches for modelling missing information without using nulls.

You can choose a value to represent missing. It's quite hard to genrealize so here are a few examples. For the `end_date` attribute in an open-ended period (i.e. has started but is in progress and not yet finished), use a far-future date such as  `9999-12-31`. For a `person_middle_name` attributte, Joe Celko suggests placing metadata values in double-curly braces e.g. `{{NK}}` for 'not known', `{{NA}}` for 'not applicable', etc.

Another somewhat intuitive approach for modelling missing information is by the absence of a row in a table. If an employee is unsalaried then do not add a row for them in the `Payroll` table, thus making them distinct from a salaried employee who is currently receiving no salary represented by a `salary_amount` of zero in the `Payroll` table.

A further approach is by the presence of a row in a table. You could have tables for `Salaried`, `Unsalaried` and `SalaryUnknown` and ensure every employee has one row in exactly one of these tables (perhaps enforced in MySQL using triggers and/or procedures).